# how to detect blobs in an image using emgu?

Tags: c#, emgucv

The older version of EMGU ( < 4.5.2) we could find blobs easily using the blobdetector and cvblobs methods like this :

```
     Emgu.CV.Cvb.CvBlobs resultingImgBlobs = new Emgu.CV.Cvb.CvBlobs();
     Emgu.CV.Cvb.CvBlobDetector bDetect = new Emgu.CV.Cvb.CvBlobDetector();
     uint numWebcamBlobsFound = bDetect.Detect(greyThreshImg, resultingImgBlobs);
```

But in the latest version, there is no CVblobs and BlobDetector, there is a simpleblobdetector class but its useless.

Does anyone knows or can point me to some documentation on how to find blobs in the new version (4.5.5) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SimpleBlobDetector`, it is what you are looking for.
You find it "useless" beacuase you didn't set it up correctly according to your usecase.
To set its parameters you need to use `SimpleBlobDetectorParams`.

Here is an example:

```
SimpleBlobDetector simpleBlobDetector = new SimpleBlobDetector(new SimpleBlobDetectorParams()
                {
                    FilterByCircularity = true,
                    FilterByArea = true,
                    MinCircularity = 0.7f,
                    MaxCircularity = 1.0f,
                    MinArea = 500,
                    MaxArea = 10000
                });
```

Here are just some parameters, you can find more about them in [Emgu Documentation](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.5/document/html/T_Emgu_CV_Features2D_SimpleBlobDetectorParams.htm)

Comment: I tried it with params, it returns MKeypoints, but I was unable to draw those keypoints on the image, usually we draw vectorofkeypoints. The new version is very consufing.

Comment: You need to convert those `MKeyPoints` to a `VectorOfKeyPoint` and then use `Features2DToolbox.DrawKeypoints` method to draw them. (https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.5/document/html/M_Emgu_CV_Features2D_Features2DToolbox_DrawKeypoints.htm)

Comment: Can you guide me on how to convert it. I tried using ToArray() but it doesn't accept that.

Comment: you need to create a new `VectorOfKeyPoint` while passing your `mKeyPoints` in the constructor. example: `VectorOfKeyPoint vectorOfKeyPoint = new VectorOfKeyPoint(mKeyPoints);`